# Replacing std::transform, inserting into a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stl-algorithm

I'm looking to insert values into a std::vector in a way like std::transform. std::transform needs a pre-sized third argument, but in my case, the size depends on transformers() and is not predictable.

```
...
// std::vector<int> new_args(); <-- not working
std::vector<int> new_args(args.size());
std::transform(args.begin(),args.end(),new_args.begin(),transformers());
```

Is there a std:transform-ish way to insert values into a std::vector?

Comment: [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) may help

Comment: How does size depend on `transformers`? Do you do some kind of filtering? If so, how do you know if something was filtered? Please clarify.

Comment: `std::vector<int> new_args();` declares a function (most vexing parse), it should be `std::vector<int> new_args;` or `std::vector<int> new_args{};`. (then `std::back_inserter` for your real problem).

Comment: @Karoly yes, it's a kind of filtering. For example, if args[1].size()==1, nothing should be added to new_args.

Comment: @user1587451: Add *full* explanation, and perhaps code. Also, search for `transform_if` (not part of the standard).

Answer (score 7):

You do not need to pre size the vector that is going to be filled with transform.  Using a [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) It will act like an iterator to the vector but will actually call `push_back()` to insert the elements into the vector.

So you code would look like

```
std::vector<int> new_args;
new_args.reserve(args.size); // use this so you don't have grow the vector geometrically.
std::transform(args.begin(),args.end(),std::back_inserter(new_args),transformers());
```

Comment: `You do not need to pre size the vector that is going to be filled with transform` how so? If I want to push_back 50000 elements, I would like to reserve that.

Comment: @Lorac the `back_inserter` works by calling `push_back` so it will resize the vector when needed. If you do not want that then you need to call `reserve` after you default construct the vector.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::back_inserter` which uses `.push_back` to add values to the vector:

```
std::vector<int> new_args;
std::transform(args.begin(),args.end(),std::back_inserter(new_args),transformers());
```

BTW: `std::vector<int> new_args();` is a function declaration. You can create an empty `std::vector` with `std::vector<int> new_args;`

Answer (score 1):

Thank god, there's boost::range.

As input and output differs in size and type, std::copy_if and std::transform did not help.

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext/push_back.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

struct is_even
{
    bool operator()(int x) const {return x%2==0;}
};

struct to_square_root
{
    float operator()(int x) const {return std::sqrt(x);}
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> input={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::vector<float> output;

    boost::push_back (
        output
      , input
      | boost::adaptors::filtered(is_even())
      | boost::adaptors::transformed(to_square_root())
    );

    for(auto i: output) std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```